# Calculate proportion by groups for a subset of the dataset

Tags: r

This might be very simple, but since im not getting into it, Im posting here with hope to get some help.

I want to calculate the proportion and standard error of proportion by group for a dataset of categorical variables. So I have 2 variables `v1` is from 1 to 4 and `v2` is from 1 to 9. I want to calculate the proportion of 1 (also for 2,3...9 ( in `v2`)) by group of `v1`.

To do by hand is easy because use of `table(v1, v2)`, but I dont want to do by hand :)

Said in more simple way: I want to find % but we can use mean as it is numeric variable. We have 1000 people, 300 are in category 1 of `v1`, 200 in category 2 of `v1` etc. The same for `v2`, 400 in category 1 and so on. If I calculate the % of category 1 (`v1`) by groups of `v2`, then will be 300/400, 200/400 and so on.

dataframe sample

```
id   v1   v2
1    1    1
2    1    1
3    2    1
4    2    1
5    3    2
6    3    2
7    4    2
```

desired output: propotion by group `v2: group 1 (v2=1) 2/4; 2/4; 2/4; 1/4. v2: group 2 (v2=2) 2/3; 2/3; 2/3; 1/3`

hope it makes sense!

Comment: I want to find % but we can use mean as it is numeric variable. We have 1000 people, 300 are in category 1 of v1, 200 in category 2 of v2 etc. The same for v2, 400 in category 1 and so on. If I calculate the % of category 1(v1) by groups of v2, then will be 300/400, 200/400 and so on.

Comment: @KFB added a sample of dataframe

Comment: Why are there 4 values (2/4; 2/4; 2/4; 1/4) for v2==1, when there are only 1 and 2 (two each) in v1?

Comment: Don't get it. how to get 2/4, 1/4 ? 2/3, 1/3 ?

Comment: 2/4 because there are two people with 1 in v1... same logic for others. For example, how many people smoke by age group. so v1 smoking group and v2 is age group. if v1=1 means they smoke 10 cigarettes a day, if is 2, 20 cigarettes a day etc...

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dt)[v1==1,list(meanv2=mean(v2), sev2=se(v2)),by=v3]
```

If v1==1 , mean(v1) will be equal to 1.

Comment: Thanks for this. This might be correct code but doesnt work in my case. Probably i didn't explained well, so im updating all post. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer of my question above, but in same time im asking another question.
I found the code to do this, however I need in addition to calculate the standard error

```
tapply(dt$v1, dt$v2, function(x){prop.table(table(x))})
```

The standard error is with this formula `SE = sqrt(p*(1-p)/n)` where `p=proportion` and `n=total population`.

My question will  be: How to include the SE in the code above?

Thanks you in advance!