# Calculate proportions group-wise from dataframe

Tags: r

I have a dataframe of word frequencies, such as:

```
df <- data.frame(
    Predictor = c("for","of","as","for","for","as","of","of","as","for"),
    ToPredict = c("sure","course","much","him","keeps","far","them","this","an","petes"),
    Freq = c(53,32,21,17,13,5,3,2,2,1))
```

I want to calculate a new column that is the proportion that each ToPredict makes up of each predictor.

So, in the above example, the values for this new column would be:

```
df$Props = c(0.631,0.865,0.75,0.202,0.155,0.179,0.081,0.054,0.071,0.012)
```

At the moment, I have a dataframe of sums:

```
sums <- aggregate(df$Freq, by=list(Category=df$Predictor), FUN=sum)
```

and I have tried:

```
df$Props <- with(df, Freq/sums$x[which(sums$Category == Predictor)])
```

Obviously, this does not work. But I do not know what will. Any help is most appreciated.

Comment: I've got a sneaking suspicion this is a duplicate question, but `with(df, ave(Freq, Predictor, FUN=prop.table) )` should do it.

Comment: Possible duplicate candidates, though the answers aren't great - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15009011/calculate-proportions-within-subsets-of-a-data-frame and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26885819/calculate-proportion-by-groups-for-a-subset-of-the-dataset

Comment: It's quite possible that it is. However, I could not find the answer with quite a bit of searching. Your solution works. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, I saw that one, and could not follow it to a successful conclusion. Thanks, again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a=aggregate(df$Freq, by=list(df$Pred), FUN=sum)
a1=a[,2]
names(a1)=as.character(a[,1])
df$Props=df$Freq/a1[df$Pred]
```

Comment: This one works, too. And is more intuitive to me (though I'd imagine slower since it creates an extra vector). Still, I can't accept my (thelatemail's) answer (at least not immediately). So this will work.

Comment: @BdEngineer I don't know SQL

Comment: @BdEngineer whatever

Answer (score 2):

Per thelatemail:

```
with(df, ave(Freq, Predictor, FUN=prop.table))
```